# Get all equal fields

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to let mysql give me all rows that have equal entries in one column, regardless how they look?

For now I use some lines of code but I would like to let mysql do the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return what you need, I think.  The question is very vague.

```
-- Depending on your SQL syntax, this might work:

SELECT COUNT(*), colname FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY colname HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

-- or similarly,

SELECT FIELD, COUNT(FIELD) AS NumOccurrences 
FROM TABLE GROUP BY FIELD HAVING ( COUNT(FIELD) > 1 )

-- or if trying to find a duplicate combination 
-- of multiple columns,

SELECT column1, column2, column3, COUNT(column3) 
FROM TABLE GROUP BY column1, column2, column3 
HAVING COUNT(column3) > 1
```

'Found at http://psoug.org/snippet/mySQL-Find-all-duplicates-in-a-column_353.htm'

Answer (score 2):

```
Select field1, field2, field3
from Table
Where field3 = "Value"
```

Like that?  Is there more to your question?

Comment: sry, that is a little bit too easy :D I want mysql to command mysql something like: "get every person with the same birthday".
Btw. Currently I do it like that, but I am asking if it is possible to do it in one (mysql) command...

Comment: Update your question with your comment.  My answer isn't right with that additional information.  :)  But giving that additional information should get you a good answer.